# compute parameter m if vectors are co-planer

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the value of m in vector *c* so that *a*, *b*, and *c* are on the same plane?
$a=(2, -2, -1)$
$b=(-3, 2, 1)$
$c=(m, 2, m)$
I think if vectors are coplanar they should lay in one plane => (a x b) * c = 0, so 2*2*m -2*m -6 -2*m -6*m - 4 = 0 . And i got m= -5/3 , am i correct?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  to format your questions

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the determinant $$ \det\begin {bmatrix}2&-2&-1\\-3&2&1\\m&2&m\end {bmatrix} =0$$

I found $m=1$ and checked it.

Comment: yes, i found my mistake, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, let $ax+by=c$ we obtain

- $2x-3y=m $
- $-2x+2y=2$
- $-x+y=m$

the associated augmented matrix is

$$\begin {vmatrix}2&-3&m\\-2&2&2\\-1&1&m\end {vmatrix}\to \begin {vmatrix}2&-3&m\\-2&2&2\\-2&2&2m\end {vmatrix}\to \begin {vmatrix}2&-3&m\\-2&2&2\\0&0&2m-2\end {vmatrix}$$

thus the system has a unique solution $\iff m=1$ that is

- $2x-3y=1 $
- $-2x+2y=2$

from which we obtain $x=-4,y=-3$ indeed

$$-4\cdot (2,-2,-1)-3\cdot (-3,2,1)=(1,2,1)$$

Comment: Many thanks for such a good explanation!!!

Comment: @tomaspak You are welcome, this way is useful since we can find easily the condition on $m$ without evaluate the determinant and we can also find the combination of the coplanar solution.

Comment: @tomaspak As a suggestion do not delete the OP since it could be useful also for othe users. Moreover remember that you can accept an answer among the given if you think that the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work